# PHP - array element issue

Tags: php, arrays

First, I'm not experienced with PHP whatsoever. I have 2 arrays - minimumpressure and maximumpressure. They both access data from a database and to create a simple xml file as you can see below:-

```
<pressuremaxhourly>1010,1009,1009,1009,1008,1008,1007,1005,1004,1003,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1001,1001,1001</pressuremaxhourly>
<pressureminhourly>1001,1009,1009,1008,1008,1006,1005,1004,1003,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001</pressureminhourly>
```

The problem is, as you can see, the 1st value of the minimum array is always equal to the last value of the maximum array ( in this case "1001"). These arrays are overwritten every half hour or so with new values, yet the the problem still exists. Here's the code I use:-

```
$MaxPressure="select hour(datetime) AS hour, max(BarometricPressure) as MAXBP from minute WHERE DATETIME
BETWEEN (CURDATE() + INTERVAL (SELECT hour(NOW())) hour - INTERVAL 24 hour)
AND ((CURDATE() + INTERVAL (SELECT hour(NOW()))hour))
group by hour
order by (CURDATE() + INTERVAL (SELECT hour(NOW())) hour - INTERVAL 24 hour)";
$MaxPressureResult = mysql_query($MaxPressure) or  die('Failed to query'.mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($MaxPressureResult)) {
    $maxpressure[]=$row->MAXBP;
}

$MinimumPressure="select hour(datetime) AS hour, min(BarometricPressure) as MINBP from minute WHERE DATETIME
BETWEEN (CURDATE() + INTERVAL (SELECT hour(NOW())) hour - INTERVAL 24 hour)
AND ((CURDATE() + INTERVAL (SELECT hour(NOW()))hour))
group by hour
order by (CURDATE() + INTERVAL (SELECT hour(NOW())) hour - INTERVAL 24 hour)";
$MinimumPressureResult = mysql_query($MinimumPressure) or  die('Failed to query'.mysql_error());


while ($minrow = mysql_fetch_object($MinimumPressureResult)) {
    $minimumpressure[]=$minrow->MINBP;
}
```

And here's the code used to create the xml file:-

```
$dom = new DOMDocument(); 
$root = $dom->createElement( "weatherdata" );
$dom->appendChild( $root );  
$item = $dom->createElement( 'item', "" );  
$root->appendChild($item);

$maxpressure = $dom->createElement( 'pressuremaxhourly', "$maxpressure[0],$maxpressure[1],$maxpressure[2],$maxpressure[3],$maxpressure[4], etc....for all values );  
$item ->appendChild($maxpressure);
$minimumpressure = $dom->createElement( 'pressureminhourly', "$minimumpressure[0],$minimumpressure[1],$minimumpressure[2],$minimumpressure[3],$minimumpressure[4], etc....for all values );  
$item ->appendChild($minimumpressure);
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->save('Hourly.xml')
```

Note: I've checked the data in the database and it's correct, so it's clearly the script that's the problem.
Sorry for the long question and code sample, hopefully someone can help.

***#####$$$$$ Update $$$$$$#######***
It seems the SQL script isn't the problem. I've left the interval at 24, and when I run the SQL script in my SQL workbench it's loading the correct results.

However when it's run from the script above, the first element is always equal to the last element. IE. (minpressure[0] == minpressure[23])

Any further thoughts?

Comment: The SQL's are returning the correct results and the arrays contain the correct elements right? Can you check it?

Comment: Ok I've run the SQL's and they're returning the same result as the above, so it's obviously the SQL script... Again, not very experienced with SQL, but I've a feeling "hour - INTERVAL 24 hour" should be 23 instead?

Comment: Yes, since you are using BETWEEN, it'll include the first and last boundaries too. Try and check the results.

Comment: See update above. Basically, the script runs fine with the correct results in my SQL workbench, but not from the script...

Comment: Did you use my code in my answer?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using your code to create the file, but it's the content that's the problem. Also, it IS the script thats wrong in fact.. Is there a better way of running a similar script for what I need? I obviously want the min/max values for the past 24 hours...

Comment: Are you sure the SQL's are returning the right data? Cause I cant see anything wrong in your code. I think 95% the SQL is wrong. And I can't do anything without an example data with your table structure.

Comment: To clarify, the SQL's are returning the wrong data. The first element is returning the same value as the last element. When I chance the code to (SELECT hour(NOW())) hour - INTERVAL 23 hour), I no longer have this problem. I'm guessing the reason for this is because the Max Pressure from 24 hours ago is being overwritten with the current hour...Does that make sense?

Comment: Are you joking? You have a three layer code here, 1: SQL, 2: data access layer, 3: building the xml. And you made me check everything twice for you, now you are saying the SQL is wrong again, as I we fixed that error 7 comments before. And yet you still insisted the code was wrong, and now we're back to square one. Good luck with your code. I've given the answer to you in my first comment.

Comment: I really appreciate your input and sorry for the inconvenience. I was almost certain the SQL code was right earlier, obviously not. Like you suggested earlier I'll use the Interval 23 value. Going to accept your answer for the help you've done. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about creating the xml file like this :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument(); 
$root = $dom->createElement( "weatherdata" );
$dom->appendChild( $root );  
$item = $dom->createElement( 'item', "" );  
$root->appendChild($item);

$maxpressure = $dom->createElement( 'pressuremaxhourly', implode(",",$maxpressure) );  
$item ->appendChild($maxpressure);
$minimumpressure = $dom->createElement( 'pressureminhourly', implode(",",$minpressure));  
$item ->appendChild($minimumpressure);
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->save('Hourly.xml')
```

Comment: I'm using the above to create the xml file now as it's not as long, but it still doesn't help my problem. I've updated my question, could you have a look? Thanks